2018: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Cryptography breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0         16
Users destroyed                                   6          0
Users deleted                                     6          0
Users contacted                                   5          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           288      1,161
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               46         54
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         59        170
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               50        180
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               374      2,378
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              532        517
Tags merged                                       4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            19          0
Tag synonyms created                             19          0
Revisions redacted                                2          0
Questions reopened                               70          2
Questions protected                              14          4
Questions migrated                              108          0
Questions merged                                  9          0
Questions flagged⁴                               13        870
Questions closed                              1,047         86
Question flags handled⁴                         491        392
Posts unlocked                                    1          8
Posts undeleted                                  15         96
Posts locked                                     11        150
Posts deleted⁵                                  270      1,876
Posts bumped                                      0        759
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               80          0
Comments flagged                                 17        671
Comments deleted⁶                             2,321      2,919
Comment flags handled                           275        413
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                  18        524
Answer flags handled                            491         51
All comments on a post moved to chat             95          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Cryptography without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁴ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Wishing you all a happy new year...
